# How to access mounted file systems as a guest user?

Tags: mount, permissions, guest-session

In Ubuntu 11.04 I could mount a file system in /media/foo and run `chown guest:guest /media/foo/bar -R` and have full access in the guest account. After the upgrade to 12.04 I changed my routine to reflect the new guest usernames (`chown guest[id]:guest[id] /media/foo/bar -R`) but I still can't access it as a guest user, as I don't have access privileges to /media as guest:

> ls: cannot open directory /media: Permission denied

(Very interestingly this does work if I `su` into the guest account as root). I understand this is meant as a [security measure](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/882862) but I don't see how it is done. `ls -l /` reports

```
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Sep  9 22:28 media
```

Thus my two questions: How does this restriction work and how can I access a mounted file system as a guest user, ideally without allowing access to all of the other mounted file systems?

Comment: I just found out this has something to do with an AppArmor profile constricting lightdm-guest-session-wrapper: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/849027

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access to `/media` is restricted by the AppArmor profile `/etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session`. There are two exceptions (lines 31 and 32):

```
 owner /media/ r,
 owner /media/** rmwlixk,  # we want access to USB sticks and the like
```

That allows access if `/media/foo` is owned by guest[id], which is the first alternative to solve my problem. The downside is that the guest account can create arbitrary directories and files in the root of /media/foo. I decided to explicitly poke a hole for `/media/foo/bar` and added the lines:

```
 owner /media/foo/bar rw,
```

A description of the syntax can be found here: http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-security/cha.apparmor.profiles.html

To the best of my knowledge this only allows the guest session to access `/media/foo/bar` and only if guest[id] is the owner of `bar`. Note that guest[id] still cannot access `/media/foo` itself. Thus `ls /media/foo` will fail, but `ls /media/foo/bar` works.

Lastly [reload](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor#Reload_one_profile) the profile for the changes to take effect:

```
 sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session
```