# looking for a jukebox player on ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3, music-player

I'm looking for a Jukebox player at a Party that lets anybody of the participants to add a song to the queue without having it played immediately over the song being played at the moment/cut the queue. I once had a very nice one running on Windows, but I can't get it to run with Mono. Well there must be something like that in Ubuntu I guess:

Needed features:

- fast search trough library (~20k songs)
- nice, easy to understand interface
- fading between tracks
- **normal users can only search library and queue stuff**
- superuser (of that program) has full control (is password protected)
- create & save playlist
- Should play the common formats (only audio)
- If the queue is empty, some predifined songs are played

Any ideas?

The user restriction is important. The computer will be operated by everybody there. Meaning nobody will try to hack the system, but there should be some kind of safety system that the running song will not change every 10 sek...

There is plenty of software available for Windows (like Media Monkey) surely there must be something for Linux

Answer (score 2):

Try searching with a keyword "kiosk" as a software solutions for places where users share a computer, come and go.
Check out GMusicBrowser. It might be able to do what you want.
On a [LinuxLinks](http://www.linuxlinks.com/Software/Multimedia/MP3/Players/Jukebox/) site I see a list of jukebox players - after I quick look at [Shrill](http://bobcopeland.com/shrill/) and Room Juice I see they do have the desired feature of limiting controls (adding songs to queue only) but it would be nice to find something with moderin GUI.

magu_ is asking for a program that features **prevention of songs being played right away** and that allows party people to queue songs only. Right? Reading other answers I see it might have been not explicit enough.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for your answer. I'll give Shrill a try.

Answer (score 0):

[**Rhythmbox** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rhythmbox//) is usually OK, you can fullscreen it with <kbd>F11</kbd>:

[image: Rhythmbox]

You can also organize Play Queues, cross-fade between tracks, playlists can be created and saved in the side pane.

Locking screen should prevent unwanted people from doing anything, though it could still be controlled via keyboard shortcuts unless those are disabled (<kbd>Keyboard Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Shortcuts.</kbd>).

You could create a new user with a quick to type but hard to remember password, then you could lock it when required, and unlock it. To edit and make new users, you can use ['Users and Groups'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups).

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I did look into it but it seems that double clicking does only start a new song and it is not possible to restrict user access (esential for me, since the computer will be used by computer novices and drunk people...)

Comment: Yes, but you can lock the screen.... it works quite well. Also, if this machine has important stuff on it, you could create a new user with a quick to type but hard to remember password, then you could lock it when required, and unlock it. This would also mean that if some bright spark found a way to exit it, you would not have problems then. The same method would work for JuK.

Comment: I gave it an other try and it seems to more or less solve the problem. Is there a way to disable the menu bar, specifically the jump to the next song feature...

Comment: If you are referring to the bar with the massive 'Previous', 'Play', and 'Next' buttons, no, I don't think you can. But you can right click on its menu item and remove the song slider, side pane and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can try JuK.

JuK is a powerful music player capable of managing a large music collection.<sup>[UA](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/juk/)</sup>

To install, just click [**JuK** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/juk/)

Also take a look at gmusicbrower.

gmusicbrower is a powerful graphic browser which supports libraries with a great number of songs (>10,000)<sup>[UA](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/gmusicbrowser/)</sup>

To install, just click [**gmusicbrower** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/gmusicbrowser/)

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I did look into it but it seems that it is not possible to restrict user access (esential for me, since the computer will be used by computer novices and drunk people...)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the default 'guest' account with one of the standard music players, and set the permissions on your music folder to allow guest to read but not modify.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186279/how-to-access-mounted-file-systems-as-a-guest-user) has answers explaining how to give guest access to your music. Basically, you have to add the music folder to a list of files guest users can access, using the AppArmor profiles.

To make changes, you would just log in as your normal user account, then log out when done.

Music players would be Rhythmbox, Amarok, Juk, etc, take your pick.

[More information about the guest session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession)

Answer (score 0):

Check into Neil Verplank's old Calliope jukebox, which has a web interface for management, automatically queues up random songs and allows users to queue up the songs they want to hear but those don't play until the currently-playing song completes first.  I had one of these working years ago, and was in touch with Neil yesterday to get one going again.  See sourceforge at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/kalliope/?source=directory/

It runs under Perl, and can play mp3s and OGG Vorbis files and can not only play out the line out jacks but also can stream to other clients in your home network.
Slick, elegant, simple, and you can have it run headless and then manage it via its own web server.

Answer (score 0):

hate to wake up old threads but.... silverjuke  it runs as a kiosk. Just in case someone is looking to do the same.