# Mount disk image for all users, even guest

Tags: mount, permissions, guest-session

What is the correct way to mount a disk image so all users (guest included) are able to access it?

I'm currently stuck after mounting it with:

```
sudo mount -o loop,users,ro,offset=262145048576 '/path/Disk Image.img' '/media/guest-Folder/Disk'
```

My normal user session can access it, but on a guest session I get an error: "This location could not be displayed. You don't have the permissions necessary to view the contents of Disk" while trying to view the contents in Nautilus.

Comment: The question appears to not be version specific, so I removed the sentence about using the no longer supported 15.10 version.

Answer (score 1):

The guest session is prevented to access it because of the default AppArmor setting. One way to fix it should be to open this file for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm
```

find these lines:

```
owner /{,run/}media/ r,
owner /{,run/}media/** rmwlixk,  # we want access to USB sticks and the like
```

and remove the *owner* keyword so it looks like:

```
/{,run/}media/ r,
/{,run/}media/** rmwlixk,  # we want access to USB sticks and the like
```

But that would give the guest users access to all mounted stuff, which would defeat the security scheme. So I would rather add a new rule, so it looks something like this:

```
/{,run/}media/ r,
owner /{,run/}media/** rmwlixk,  # we want access to USB sticks and the like
/media/guest-** rmwlixk,
```

Comment: Thanks, seems it didn't worked. Tried `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm` to reload the profile as suggested in http://askubuntu.com/a/190297/251621 but got `AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm in /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/authentication at line 17: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN` error.

Comment: @eridani: Try `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session` instead.